# PHP exec mocp command

Tags: php, linux, apache2, raspbian

I want to play music via PHP on my Raspberry Pi with Mocp (music on console). This command

```
mocp -S
```

works just fine in the console (it starts the server of mocp) but in PHP's exec function it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $ret = exec("mocp -S", $out, $err);
    print_r($ret);
    print_r($out);
    print_r($err);
?>
```

It just returns:

```
Array ( ) 2
```

According to [this list](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html) return_var code 2 means

> Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)

But what exactly does this mean? The command `mocp --help` works in both console and PHP exec.
How can I run mocp with every parameter in PHP?

EDIT:
I just logged in as "www-data" (the apache user) and tried to run mocp commands. I got this return:

> FATAL_ERROR: Can't create directory `/var/www/.moc`

I copied the `.moc` folder of Pi to `www-data` (with user "pi"):

```
sudo cp /home/pi/.moc/ /var/www/.moc
```

Now my script from above gives me:

> Running the server...Array ( [0] => Running the server... [1] => Running the server... ) 2

But it still does not work. In the console of www-data `mocp -S` now gives me

> FATAL_ERROR: Can't bind() to the socket

EDIT 2:
I changed the permsions on `/var/www/.moc`. If I try `mocp -S`, I get this

> Running the server...
>   Trying JACK...
>   Trying ALSA...
>   ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
>   ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
>   ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
>   ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
>   ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
>   ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
>   ALSA lib conf.c:4720:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
>   ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
>   Trying OSS...
>   FATAL_ERROR: No valid sound driver!
>   FATAL_ERROR: Server exited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like www-data user doesn't have right access permissions to use your audio device.
I belive executing this should help:

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio www-data
```

Answer (score 2):

My full solution of the problem:
I started with a new installation of raspbian and ran those comands:
`sudo raspi-config
    ->Expand Filesystem
    ->Finish, reboot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo groupadd www-data
sudo usermod -g www-data www-data
sudo apt-get install moc
sudo usermod -a -G audio www-data
mocp -S
sudo cp -R /home/pi/.moc /var/www/.moc
sudo chown www-data /var/www/.moc/
sudo chmod -R a+rwxst .moc/`
At the end user "www-data" is able to run mocp.